# What is the "todo" parameter referencing to in Todo.js (Backbone.js tutorial)?

Tags: backbone.js

In addOne(todo) I'm having trouble understanding what the parameter is being referenced from:

In the AppView:

```
initialize: function(){
    Todos.bind('add', this.addOne, this);  //So "this" keyword is being passed, which refers to AppView itself
    //More code here
},
```

then in the addOne function,

```
addOne: function(todo) {
    var view = new TodoView({model: todo});
    this.$("#todo-list").append(view.render().el);
},
```

See annotated source here: http://backbonejs.org/docs/todos.html

So isn't AppView being passed into addOne(todo)? Shouldn't a model be passed into model: todo in addOne()?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `this` that's being passed as the third parameter to the bind function is used to bind the `context` of the function to the current `context`, its not being passed as a parameter. Under the hood bind uses [underscore.js's](http://underscorejs.org/#bind) `_bind()`.

EDIT:
I think what's confusing you is that it's not obvious where the `addOne` method is being called. Basically the `add` `event` is fired when a new item is added to the collection, you are able to bind to this event and backbone will pass the newly added model to the `method` that is bound to this `event` (so in this case the `addOne` method is bound to this event and the todo is the new model). What's triggering the `add` event in this example is when a new todo is created through the `Todos.create({title: this.input.val()});` in the AppView's `createOnEnter` method.

Comment: Right. I understand that bind is passing "this" as a parameter to AddOne(), but wouldn't that cause an error, since it's referring to AppView, instead of the Todo model?

Comment: Oh! so "this" is actually referring to "Todos" instead of the view?

Comment: Not quite, it is referring to the current context, which in this case is the "AppView", this way when "this" is used inside the addOne method it is referring to the same "this" as when it was bound (otherwise "this" would refer to the `window`).